# passing field values into temp variables

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION param_labels(_region_label text, _model_label text)
RETURNS TABLE (param_label text, param_graphics_label text) LANGUAGE sql AS
$BODY$
SELECT p.param_label, p.param_graphics_label
FROM   parameters      p 
JOIN   parameter_links l USING (param_id)
JOIN   regions         r USING (region_id)
JOIN   models          m USING (model_id)
WHERE  p.active
AND    r.region_label = $1 
AND    m.model_label = $2
ORDER  BY p.param_graphics_label;
$BODY$;
```

In the above function  in SELECT clause I have 2 fields, now I need to pass those fields into two temp variables. Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: My most valuable suggestion is for you to explain what you are trying to achieve. My second most valuable suggestion is to check the [fine manual for PL/pgSQL - SQL Procedural Language](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are no "variables" in an SQL function. You may be confusing that with [PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) or some other procedural language function.

In a plpgsql function You can assign multiple variables at once using `SELECT INTO`. Example:
[Speed up plpgsql that counts doc types in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613257/speed-up-plpgsql-that-counts-doc-types-in-a-loop/11613373#11613373)

But your query does not fit the description and returns a set of rows. You may be looking for a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS
SELECT p.param_label, p.param_graphics_label FROM ...
```

Example:
[Using temp table in PL/pgSQL procedure for cleaning tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932962/using-temp-table-in-pl-pgsql-procedure-for-cleaning-tables/7942187#7942187)